# Replace newlines with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Trying to replace and render newlines in text coming from DB in HTML. Values were entered with java so values should contain '\n'. Values are displayed in a span tag which has a 'toggleBreaks' class. Code works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not on IE8. I haven't tried other IE versions, but sadly I need IE8.

```
$('.toggleBreaks').each(function(index) {
    var orgText = $(this).html();
    var regex = /\r?\n/g;
    if (regex.test(orgText)) {
      var modText = orgText.replace(regex, "<br />");
      $(this).html(modText);
    }
});
```

I was nearly able to accomplish the honoring of the existing newlines in my page simply by applying the style 'pre-wrap', but this too doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: Why is it failing in IE8? Errors?

Comment: For some reason, I've seen using `/\n\r?/g` instead

Comment: Just remove the if condition and change /\r?\n/g to /\r\n/g. That solves the problem.

Comment: @ChristianEzeani How so? I didn't realize it, but the `if` statement kind of is redundant, but I don't see how that would solve the problem. Also, using `/\r\n/g` isn't a good idea because not all browsers have the `\r` part, which you're requiring

Comment: how about /[\r\n]/g ?

Comment: @Christophe `\r\n` is a newline, so that would produce `<br /><br />`.

Comment: As an aside, the code can be simplified a _lot_ - you don't need the `.each()` or the working variables if you [pass a function to `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml): `$('.toggleBreaks').html(function(i,oldHtml){return oldHtml.replace(/\r\n/g,"<br />");});` (of course you still need to ensure you have an appropriate regex).

Comment: @Christophe, you're right. `/\r?\n/g` is correct.